# How to export mac app using a development profile via cli

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, fastlane, mac-catalyst

I want to distribute mac app to our testers.

According to [Apple: Test a beta version](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev295cc0fae)

> Export the app using a development provisioning profile

How do you do this via xcodebuild/ xcrun or fastlane?

I tried:

```
    build_app(
      catalyst_platform: 'macos',
      configuration: "Development",
      destination: "generic/platform=macOS,variant=Mac Catalyst",
      scheme: "MyScheme",
      export_options: {
        compileBitcode: false,
        installerSigningCertificate: "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer: MY COMPANY (12345ABCDE)",
        method: "development",
        provisioningProfiles: provisioningProfiles,
        signingCertificate: "Apple Development"
      }
    )
```

Which will generate command:

```
xcodebuild -scheme MyScheme -configuration Development -destination 'generic/platform=macOS,variant=Mac Catalyst'
```

However, during export, I get

> PKG invalid

If I only use the .app file, I'm getting
[image]

I also tried

```
xcodebuild archive -archivePath "AppDevelopment.xcarchive" -scheme "Development" -configuration Development -destination 'generic/platform=macOS,variant=Mac Catalyst'
```

```
xcodebuild archive -archivePath "AppDevelopment.xcarchive" -scheme "Development" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY= CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO -configuration Development -destination 'generic/platform=macOS,variant=Mac Catalyst'
```

Same result